# Can ElasticSearch express hierarchy or waterfall of OR conditions in a strict filter query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Most things here expressed in Python-ish pseudocode as that is what I am working in

### Background

We have a data process which

- produces entities where there are multiple natural keys for a single entity
- chooses one of the natural keys as the canonical natural key for the entity

So each record from the dataset is essentially:

```
class Entity:
    canonical_natural_key: str
    natural_keys: List[str]  # canonical natural key is also in this list
```

This represents real-world data with no UUID to work with until we assign one.

Now each time this data process runs, it does its best to resolve the real state of the world. A few things can happen that make it nontrivial to match a entity from one run to an entity of the next run and be sure they are in fact the same entity, namely:

- which of the natural keys is the canonical natural key can change
- the canonical natural key could be completely new, as in not previously seen in this entity's list of natural keys
- the list of natural keys can change, although we expect overlap (set intersection size > 0) between runs

### ElasticSearch Logic

What I need to do is to handle these Entity records each time the process runs and attempt to resolve them to an existing one from previous runs.

To attempt to find an already existing entity, we want to waterfall through these conditions:

1. canonical_natural_key == existing_entity.canonical_natural_key, OTHERWISE
2. canonical_natural_key in existing_entity.natural_keys, OTHERWISE
3. len(natural_keys.intersection(existing_entity.natural_keys) > 0

If all conditions fail this is in all likelihood a completely new entity.

The naive version would take 3 ElasticSearch queries, essentially:

```
existing_entity: Optional[Entity] = find_by_canonical_natural_key_match(canonical_natural_key)
if not existing_entity:
    existing_entity: Optional[Entity] = find_by_canonical_natural_key_in_natural_keys(canonical_natural_key)
if not existing_entity:
    existing_entity: Optional[Entity] = find_by_natural_keys_intersection(natural_keys)
return existing_entity
```

For performance reasons I would ideally do this in 1 or 2 queries instead of 3.

Is there a good way to do this in ElasticSearch?
I know you can boost results that match a certain field, but boost appears only to be for `match` queries, whereas I want to `filter` so we don't get any fuzzy matches, returning 0 entities if there are truly no matches.

My concern is that using a standard OR filter that treats the three conditions equally might erroneously produce some incorrect matches.
We don't want a scenario where:

- existing entity 1 matches on condition 2
- existing entity 2 matches on condition 3
  ...but existing entity 2 is returned as the top result from the search for some reason.

We would want entity 1 as the top result because satisfying condition 2 is considered a better indicator than condition 3